# Allow my SAAS user install MailChimp on their store

Tags: shopify, mailchimp, saas, mailchimp-api-v3.0

We are building SAAS platform like Shopify. Now we would like our customers to install MailChimp on their store just like Shopify customer installs on their store.

When I was trying MailChimp on Shopify platform, i noticed somehow Shopify receives some key/token from MailChimp when installation completes and then Shopify uses this key/token to update MailChimp list of that store whenever some events occurs. That's what we are looking to build.

I tried MailChimp API (on Playground) with the generated key. But, this API creates store, list etc under my account, then how do i enable this against our customer's MailChimp account?

I would greatly appreciate it if you kindly give me some feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Shopify and MailChimp use [OAuth](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31) to exchange API credentials for users accounts between each other.

In your case, you should probably check out [MailChimps OAuth 2 documentation](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/how-to-use-oauth2/) on this topic.

When it comes to integrating MailChimp with your SaaS, your application as to acts as a client to MailChimp. Use OAuth to let your users connect their MailChimp account to your application and store the Refresh and Access Tokens in your database. This allows you to make requests to the MailChimp API to access your user's MailChimp data.